# The easiest way to hide a SharePoint web (site) from users

Tags: 2007, permissions

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to hide a sharepoint Web from the users (except for administrators)?  I'm referring to the Webs in SPWeb.

If possible, I would like to see some examples on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost identical to the one that was posted on StackOverflow yesterday. [Have a look at it there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674378/hiding-a-deprecated-sharepoint-web/2674839).

Comment: I like the idea of removing access for the users, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Do I go to the web and remove the user from the group, leaving only the administrators, or are there something more to it?

Comment: Go to the sub-site, Site Actions / Site Settings / Advanced Permissions. Then Select Actions / Edit Permissions to break permission inheritance with the parent site.